# start process from ssh and be able to close connection

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, process, raspberry-pi

I'm connecting to my RaspberryPi with Raspbian installed via ssh. My problem is that I can't let the RasPi do things (e.g., installing software, performing calculations) while my computer is shut down, since the processes I launch via SSH are child processes of the SSH shell and are terminated when the connection ends. I know I can disconnect child processes from the shell, but I'm not sure which way to use it. I would like to be able to see as much of the output of the process as possible (maybe in a file?).

BTW: I'm using PuTTY from Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `screen` or `tmux` for that. I would prefer `tmux`. What tmux does is basically create different tmux sessions which keep on running even if you close your ssh session. When you reconnect later, you can re-open that session and you will see that everything is running fine.

This is a standard practice while using ssh.

For an even better interface and features, you could use `byobu` which uses either `tmux` or `screen`.

First of all, install byobu and tmux:

```
sudo apt-get install tmux byobu
```

Then run it like this:

```
byobu-tmux
```

Now, inside `byobu`, you can open several windows/tabs by pressing `F2` and switch between them using `<Alt>+Left/Right`. Or simply press `<Shift>+<F1>` to see full help.

Comment: Any chance you've got a link to a tutorial?

Comment: Dude, there is no need of a tutorial. Just do these 2 steps: 1) Install it and 2) Run it. Then, everytime when you reconnect to you RPi, just issue the `byobu-tmux` command and your previous session will open perfectly intact.

Comment: Still, if you need one, here is one good demo of using byobu: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NawuGmcvKus

Comment: tmux is great! :) Any possibility to change the color of that green bar at the bottem of the console?

Comment: Yes, definitely. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60968/tmux-bottom-bar-color-change

Answer (score 1):

As  already mentioned, you can use a software like tmux or screen to start a shell and keep it running detached, but you could also use the [nohup](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/unohup.htm) cmd to start your processes and keep them running even without any open session on the rasp.

Comment: but isn't nohup one of the things which leaves you without the process stdout?

Comment: Yes. But you can reconnect to that process using `reptyr`.

Comment: Sure you can redirect the processes output to a file.